# pandas split row and columns to match each other

Tags: python, pandas

What I have now looks like this as a single column with 250 rows in it

```
                DATA_ID\tAmount_1\tAmount2\tAmount3
0               DATA_1\t1307\t13463\t5447
1         DATA_2\t144054\t1744\t8934
2         DATA_3\t919\t4038\t16013
3      DATA_4\t135409\t113611\t96418
```

What i want is

```
DATA_ID | Amount1 | Amount2 | Amount3
data1   | 123     | 14123   | 931931
data2   | 1233    | 38823   | 123513
```

Im stuck with this , What i have tried is

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(4):
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({df.columns[0].split()[j]: [df.iloc[i].str.split()[0][j]],
                       })
```

But that doesnt seem to work.
I have found similar questions, but results were not resolver programmatically, I think that I should solve it iteratively but I don't really know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need set separator to tab in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t")
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""  DATA_ID\tAmount_1\tAmount2\tAmount3
DATA_1\t1307\t13463\t5447
DATA_2\t144054\t1744\t8934
 DATA_3\t919\t4038\t16013
DATA_4\t135409\t113611\t96418"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\t")
print (df)
    DATA_ID  Amount_1  Amount2  Amount3
0    DATA_1      1307    13463     5447
1    DATA_2    144054     1744     8934
2    DATA_3       919     4038    16013
3    DATA_4    135409   113611    96418
```

Comment: I mean you made me feel stupid and thank you for that !!
God, im quite new to pandas and oh lord how easy it became !
Thank you !